# How to display Dynamic values in Redux-form Fields and handle onChange event

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am Developing a CRUD app in REACT_REDUX, in Which I want to show a Form element with old values that can be changed and updated later. In Below Element I have tried to set Old values in Field types, But it shows null every time. values work fine with INPUT tag But it starts returning null instantly when I change it to FIELD tag.

```
const demoele = this.props.getmovie.map(d => (< div key="mydiv" id="updateForm">
            <h3 align="center" key='updateform'>UPDATE HERE</h3>
            <hr></hr>
            <form key={d} action="/" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.updateMovieDetails)} >
                <h4>Movie Name - {d.name} </h4>
                <Field key={d.name} name="update_name" type='text' component={this.renderInput} **value={d.name}** id='mname' />
                <h4>Movie Director - {d.director}</h4>
                <Field key={d.director} name="update_director" type='text' component={this.renderInput} **value={d.director}** id='mdir' />
                <h4>Movie Language - {d.language}</h4>
                <Field key={d.language} name="update_language" type='text' component={this.renderInput} **value={d.language}** id='mlang' />
                <button type='submit' >UPDATE</button>
            </form>
        </div > ))
```

Comment: did you checked is there any mismatch of the name value and the data key are same ?

Comment: can you check this one and try changing firstName to firstNames and click on load button, because the data key and name value should be same then only it will get properly mapped. Can you check this and let me know

Comment: I will check and get back to you. Thank you so much for Help

Comment: Sure let me know !!